# Getting Error while making live payments in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe as a payment gateway to make payments. I have written code from stripe official docs and its working fine in test mode. But when i try to make live payments its not working as intended. And getting errors.

Here is my code:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_your_key');

// To create a PaymentIntent for confirmation, see our guide at: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/creating-payment-intents#creating-for-automatic
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(
  'pi_test_id',
  {payment_method: 'pm_card_visa'}
);
```

Here is error i am getting from stripe:

```
Error: You cannot use the test ID 'pm_card_visa' in livemode. If you are testing your integration, please use your testmode API keys instead.
```

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem. I use real cards in live mode but I always get the same error

Answer (score 0):

As the error message mentions, you cannot use a test card in live mode. You would need to collect/use real card details for livemode payments.

I'd suggest you refer to their documentation on how to collect card details : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

Comment: I use real cards in live mode but I always get the same error

Comment: if you're sure you're using the test API keys, I suggest you reach out to Stripe Support with the request id for them to investigate further.